# How to get dataframe of unique ids

Tags: python, pandas, duplicates

I'm trying to group the following dataframe by unique binId and then parse the resulting rows based of 'z' and pick the row with highest value of 'z'. Here is my dataframe.

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.DataFrame({'ID':['1','2','3','4','5','6'], 'binId': ['1','2','2','1','1','3'], 'x':[1,4,5,6,3,4], 'y':[11,24,35,16,23,34],'z':[1,4,5,2,3,4]})
```

`
I tried following code which gives required answer,

```
def f(x):
    tp = df[df['binId'] == x][['binId','ID','x','y','z']].sort_values(by='z', ascending=False).iloc[0]
    return tp`
```

and then,

```
binids= pd.Series(df.binId.unique())
print binids.apply(f)
```

The output is,

```
binId ID  x   y  z
0     1  5  3  23  3
1     2  3  5  35  5
2     3  6  4  34  4
```

But the execution is too slow. What is the faster way of doing this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [`idxmax`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.core.groupby.DataFrameGroupBy.idxmax.html) for indices of `max` and select by `loc`:

```
df1 = df.loc[df.groupby('binId')['z'].idxmax()]
```

Or faster is use [`sort_values`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.sort_values.html) with [`drop_duplicates`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.drop_duplicates.html):

```
df1 = df.sort_values(['binId', 'z']).drop_duplicates('binId', keep='last')

print (df1)
  ID binId  x   y  z
4  5     1  3  23  3
2  3     2  5  35  5
5  6     3  4  34  4
```